# Binary operator == can not be applied to two Int32 oprarands in swift

Tags: swift

I am try to execute SQLite's select statement.

```
var str = NSString (format: "select   cat_id,Cat_Title,Cat_author,Cat_content,Cat_Date,Cat_excerpt,Cat_featured_image_url,Cat_permalink,Cat_selected_id from main_table mainorder = %i and subindex = %i",mainordervalue,subordervalue)
    var sql  :Character; (str as NSString).UTF8String
    var stalement : COpaquePointer = nil
if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql , tooBig, &stalement, nil) !=  SQLITE_OK
```

on if statement I am facing issue is that.

> Binary operator == can not be applied to two Int32 operands.

Please help me where I did mistake.

Comment: I doubt that the Swift compiler uses the word "oprarands". Use copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the error message is misleading somehow, and that you don't really have two `Int32` operands.

Try explicitly casting both arguments to `Int` and see what happens:

```
if Int(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql , tooBig, &stalement, nil)) !=  Int(SQLITE_OK)
```

Whatever the types are, they should both fit into an `Int`, and should be comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the error message doesn't actually describe what's going wrong here. What you need to do is make sure the arguments being passed to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` are of the correct types. In this case, your problem variables are `sql` and `tooBig`.

Your query string can be written in Swift much more cleanly and concisely with string interpolation. You should be able to pass the resulting `String` directly to the function.

Meanwhile, you don't show it, but let's assume your `tooBig` is defaulting to the Swift type `Int`. `sqlite3_prepare_v2` expects a primitive C integer for that argument. To resolve this, cast to `CInt`.

Taken together, it should look something like:

```
var mainOrderValue, subIndexValue: Int
var tooBig: CInt
// set values for these variables

...

let sql = "select * from main_table where mainorder = \(mainOrderValue) and subindex = \(subIndexValue)"

var statement: COpaquePointer = nil

if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, tooBig, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    // error handling
}
```

Note that these guidelines will also hold true for other sqlite3 functions. For instance, if you want to bind an integer to a query using `sqlite3_bind_int`, it might look something like:

```
var statement: COpaquePointer = nil

let sql = "select * from some_table where some_column = ?"

if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
    // error handling
}

let someInt: Int = 5

if sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, CInt(someInt)) != SQLITE_OK {
    // error handling
}
```